# Why doesn't array filter search work in react native after building apk with expo

Tags: arrays, react-native

I have a problem with my code in react native. I want to search out names from an array. I am getting this array from an api. I am passing the array into the empty dataBackUp array in the state so I can filter or search through it in the front end. But when I search before building the app apk on expo, it works. But after building the app apk with expo, it does not work. Please I need someone to help me. A piece of my code is below.

```
this.state = {
  dataBackUp: []
}
searchName(name){

   let filtered = [];
    
   this.state.dataBackUp.filter(v => (               
    v.name.toLowerCase().includes(name.toLowerCase()) ? filtered.push(v) : ''         
   ));
    
    this.setState({dataBackUp: filtered});
}
```

Comment: Can you change v.name.toLowerCase().includes(name.toLowerCase()) ? filtered.push(v) : ''   to v.name.toLowerCase().includes(name.toLowerCase()) ? filtered.push(v) : null

Comment: Did not work for me, but thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
searchName = searchString => {
   const {dataBackUp} = this.state;
   const tempList = dataBackUp.filter(
        v => v.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchString.toUpperCase()) !== -1,
      );

   this.setState({
      dataBackUp: [...tempList],
   });
}
```

Comment: Wow, well done and thank you. It worked perfectly for me.